# c# configuration manager

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection, connection-string

Hello im having trouble with my connection when i transfer my code to another pc. Here in its original computer it is working fine. But in another computer it says connection error. Im sure about the new connection string on that pc is correct so i think it has something to do with configuration manager.
The other pc has same version of visual studio and sql express

App config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MPnew.Properties.Settings.MARISCHELLdatabaseConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=BENJOPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MARISCHELLdatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  <add name ="cnn" connectionString="Data Source=BENJOPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MARISCHELLdatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Connection code:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                cnn.Open();

            // continue code

        }
```

Comment: it highly depends on what you want to happen. Is that other pc named `BENJOPC` and do you want to connect from any computer to that SQLEXPRESS instance then you have to make sure the SqlExpress instance is listening on your network interface and the firewall is open. If you want to make a local connection to the users own sqlexpress instance replace `BENJOPC` with a single dot `.`, it might help if you search for the exact exception  you get.You're not the first to encounter this issue

Answer (score 1):

I think **BENJOPC\SQLEXPRESS** is giving wrong connection message. I suggest to use correct server name or you could just use .\SQLEXPRESS instead of BENJOPC\SQLEXPRESS.